# Interface 'NodeModule' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Module' and 'Module'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, yarnpkg, package.json

I'm use React.
After create-react-app --typescript I've added few libraries to package.json after that I received exception in runtime.

```
TypeScript error in D:/catalog/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(223,11):
Interface 'NodeModule' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Module' and 'Module'.
  Named property 'hot' of types 'Module' and 'Module' are not identical.  TS2320

    221 | declare var require: NodeRequire;
    222 |
  > 223 | interface NodeModule {
        |           ^
    224 |     exports: any;
    225 |     require: NodeRequireFunction;
    226 |     id: string;
```

I tried
1) remove node_moduls/install again
2) clear cache

Fortunatly my project builds, but exception appear in runtime
My package.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/bootstrap": "^4.2.0",
        "@types/faker": "^4.1.4",
        "@types/node": "12.11.2",
        "@types/parcel-env": "^0.0.0",
        "@types/ramda": "^0.25.48",
        "@types/react-dom": "16.9.2",
        "@types/react-router": "^4.4.3",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "@types/recompose": "^0.30.3",
        "@types/styled-components": "4.1.16",
        "react": "^16.10.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
        "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
        "remotedev": "^0.2.9",
        "yarn-deduplicate": "^1.1.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "16.8.19",
        "@types/enzyme": "^3.9.0",
        "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.5",
        "@types/jest": "^23.3.10",
        "@types/webpack": "^4.4.24",
        "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.6",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.12.1",
        "lerna": "^3.15.0",
        "prettier": "^1.15.3",
        "tslint": "^5.12.0",
        "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.17.0",
        "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.4.0",
        "tslint-loader": "^3.5.4",
        "tslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.0.1",
        "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
        "typescript": "3.6.4",
        "typescript-plugin-styled-components": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "@types/react": "16.8.19"
    },
}
```

React/typescript/yarn.

Answer (score 3):

Try updating `@types/webpack-env` to latest version. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that the version of `@types/node` you've specify in your `package.json`'s `devDependencies` is incompatible with the one used under the hood by one of your dependencies.

For instance you will get this error if you've specified `"@types/node": "13.9.1"` but use a `"@nestjs/cli": "^7.0.0"` because that latter lib is using itself `"@types/node": "12.12.31"`.

A workaround for this is to lower your the `@types/node` version of your project to the lowest common denominator, so `"12.12.31"` in this example.

Answer (score 0):

After moved all @types to devDependencies exception doesn't appear

Comment: Even if you upgrade `@types/node` to v13?